# Allocate memory to an object c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, memory, memory-management

I am tasked with creating a simple telephone network simulation that includes different types of phone, some of which will have a SMS style function. I would like to be able to simulate these phones having a limited memory capacity. I could simply limit the number of messages a phone can have stored but I think it would be a more elegent solution to use system RAM. Is there a simple way to do this in c#.

There will be a phone class with a textphone class that inherits from it and each phone will be an object created from this.

Comment: You could use a virtual machine and only allocate a small amount of ram to it.

Comment: This makes no sense, you don't control RAM on a virtual memory operating system.  Simply create a List<> that you won't allow to grow beyond a certain limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use buffer array , or  memory mapped files

Comment: Just googled that and it sounds promising. Would it be possible to allocate both my SMS's and contact books to the same one whilst still maintaining them as seperate entities?

Comment: well, i was waiting to see if anyone else had any ideas..but i have to reward your cheek (and your answer) thanks :)